# Calabi–Yau theorem and complex Monge–Ampère equation for transversally Kähler manifolds

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, foliations, calabi-yau, sasakian-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact smooth
manifold, and $F\subset TM$ a smooth
foliation. It is called **transversally Kähler**
if the normal bundle $TM/F$ is equipped with
a Hermitian structure (that is, a complex structure
and a Hermitian metric) which is locally obtained
as a pullback of a Kähler structure on the leaf
space. Sasakian manifolds are prime examples of
transversally Kähler manifolds (the leaf space
of the Reeb foliation on a Sasakian manifolds
is Kähler).

A differential form on $M$ is called **basic**
if it vanishes on $F$ and is locally obtained
as a pullback of a form on the leaf space.
The basic forms are preserved by de Rham differential,
and the cohomology of the basic forms is called
**the basic cohomology**.

A foliation is **taut** if the top basic cohomology
is non-zero (this is not the usual definition, but a theorem of
Habib and Richardson). For taut foliations, one has also
Poincaré duality on the basic cohomology, and the
identification between the basic cohomology and the basic
harmonic forms if a transversal Riemannian structure
is given.

When $F$ is taut and transversally
Kähler, the basic cohomology satisfy all the nice properties
of the cohomology of the Kähler manifolds: the dd^c-lemma,
the Hodge decomposition, the Hodge structure, Lefschetz
SL(2)-action and so on. This is a folklore result of sorts,
which follows (without much difficulty) from the
Habib–Richardson theorem identifying the basic
cohomology and basic harmonic forms.

I think I can prove the Calabi–Yau theorem (that is,
the uniqueness and existence of the solutuions of
the complex Monge–Ampère equation) for
the basic forms; the proof is essentially the
same as the usual Calabi–Yau, with the only
(minor) modification in the $C^0$-estimates.
The result is as follows.

THEOREM: Let $V$ be a basic volume form, and
$\omega$ a transversal Kähler form on
a taut foliated manifold $(M, F)$, with $\operatorname{dim}(M) -\operatorname{rk}(F)=k$.
Assume that  $\int_{M/F} V = \int_{M/F} \omega^k$,
where $\int_{M/F}$ denotes the projection to the
top degree basic cohomology class, given by
the tautness of $F$. Then there exists a
basic function $\phi$ such that
$(\omega+dd^c \phi)^k=V$, and $\phi$
is unique up to a constant.

I suspect the result is already known in some
other disguise. Could someone please enlighten
me if this is known, and what are the
good terms I should look in Google for
this kind of stuff? From the search
it is painfully obvious that "transversally
Kähler" is something that only Sasakian people
know and use. I suspect some other term is
commonly used instead of "transversally
Kähler", because the notion is ubiquitous.

Comment: Markdown note: `K\"ahler` doesn't work here (it renders as `K"ahler`).  Instead, one must use Unicode directly, like Kähler.  I edited accordingly.

Comment: A version of the "transverse Calabi-Yau theorem" is proven by Kacimi-Alaoui in "Opérateurs transversalement elliptiques sur un feuilletage riemannien et applications", Compositio 1990. I'm not sure how his "homologically orientable" condition compares to your "taut" condition. The main point of Kacimi-Alaoi is to develop the linear elliptic theory in the transverse setting, after which he says everything goes through.

Comment: many thanks! I will read it carefully, but it looks like it contains the answer